# multiple boolean expressions without reinserting the variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there a way to put multiple `boolean_expression` into an if statement without reinserting the variable?

Example:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 4;
if( Map[y][x] == 0 || Map[y][x] == 1 ){...}
```

without repeating `Map[ ][ ]`?

I'm new here and it would speed up my coding much more;

Comment: You could write a `switch` / `case`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if I remember correctly you can set only one Boolean expression for every case:

Comment: Sure, but you can fallthrough `case`s. Wait, was swapping the index parameters in your sample intentional? Then there's no other way to write that, no.

Comment: explain how you are deciding the order of `y` and `x` for each case

Comment: You are not repeating anything. `Map[y][x]` is not the same as `Map[x][y]`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt OPS I just saw that I used first Map[y][x] ad then  Map[x][y] i meant to say Map[y][x] and Map[y][x]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: the original question was mistyped, according to the OP. Most of the following applies to what was originally asked.

No. Unfortunately, C++ is not a telepathic language. Here, I presume that `Map` is some kind of a two-dimensional vector, or something that conceptually resembles a two-dimensional vector, and `operator[]` is used to access its members.

So, if here your intentions are to compare two values in this two-dimensional vector-like object, then you cannot avoid using `operator[]` both times. Because that's the only means for referencing values in this object. If you have to reference or access something in your object, that's the only way to do it. And if you have to do it for two values, you cannot get around the basic fact that you have to do it twice.

Having said that, if you have to frequently compare two related values in the map -- that is, two values with indexes that are related in the same way as in your example -- you can certainly write a small facade for it:

```
template<typename obj, typename coord_t, typename value_t>
auto obj_contains2(obj &&Obj, coord_t x, coord_t y, value_t a, value_t b)
{
    return Obj[x][y] == a || Obj[x][y] == b;
}
```

And then use:

```
if (obj_contains2(Map, x, y, a, b))
```

But you're not really avoiding the use of the operators here, just moving them into a corner. You still have to use operator[] twice. Somewhere.

Comment: could you edit your Answer, I miss typed instead of Map[y][x] Map[y][x] I typed Map[y][x] Map[x][y]

Comment: Your typo changes the fundamentals of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do it like this:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 4;
auto val = Map[y][x];
if( val == 0 || val == 1 ){...}
```

Comment: I'm not that comfortable with C++11 auto , I'm still trying to fully learn basics

Comment: Auto is not important here, I used it because I don't know what is the result  type of Map[y][x]. If you know that Map[y][x] returns int, you can replace auto with int. The point is that you use variable (named val) to save the result of searching the map and this variable is used in further expressions. This way map is searched only once.